# Document into Android Application

Tags: android

I have a document file which I need to convert into application.

E.g., with menu and navigation of a book, rather than directly opening a pdf by the user.

There are similar applications such as eBook apps which basically has only one eBook in them but offers navigation and page by page access features.

** My request: Comment before vote down. It'll be help for my future questions.

Comment: you want to create an application that is actually a document?!

Comment: @Thepoosh, Yeah. If there are any wrong in my question correct it.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vasithwam.tamil.thirumurai.thirumanthiram

Comment: above the link is a book. That is created as android application.

Comment: It is just an app, filled with content ;) Probably also with functionality....

Comment: if you want an app the displays a document you need to create it with UI. just saying I want a document to be an app has no meaning

Comment: Just create the application and fill it with the content of the document! Maybe you can work with an import function ?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be discouraged by the votes down but you must have investigated enough before placing such question.

Thirumathiram showing texts doesn't mean it was showing a text file. The text may be loaded from sqlite, or from a webservice or even from a text file. but text file is not the application.

1. Read the content of the textfile
2. load it in the view (you must have a logic for pagination)

I hope this would give you a heads up.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

See [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example).  In principle, it provides everything you need; you only have to replace the array that holds the content.